# Docker, copiando archivos en nginx

Tags: docker, nginx

a todos.

Estoy aprendiendo Docker, cuando intento cargar los archivos de mi directorio website/ ubicado en el escritorio, me genera el siguiente error:

docker: invalid reference format.
See 'docker run --help'.

Ya valide que los comandos funcionen dentro del Visual Studio Code, pero no me deja realizar la siguiente instrucción:

docker run -p 80:88 -d --name website -v $(pwd):/usr/share/nginx/html/:ro nginx

Alguien que me pueda ayudar, por favor.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: el :ro no me suena de nada, creo que docker lo toma como un comando, intenta eliminar esa parte de la cadena a ver si funciona

Comment: Acabe de hacerlo, pero aún me genera el error;  <br >PS C:\Users\impac\Desktop\website> docker run --name website -v $(pwd):/usr/share/nginx/html -d nginx   
docker: invalid reference format.
See 'docker run --help'.
PS C:\Users\impac\Desktop\website>

Comment: Estoy ejecutando los comandos en Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error lo tienes en `pwd`. Usa llaves en lugar de parentesis.

Cambia a lo siguiente

```
... -v ${pwd}:/usr/share/nginx
```

Comment: Ya lo probé, funciona, ¡Muchas gracias! ¿Tienes algún tutorial de comandos Docker, para Windows?

Comment: No amigo. El detalle que tenias era de powershell. No docker.